# Web Hosting on VPS

Tags: php, dns

I registered a domain name and a VPS with GoDaddy. Created a user account on the WHM cpanel. Via my IP/cpanel i have been able to access my cpanel and upload files on the server, but i can not access my site using my domain name. I can only access the uploaded files via my IP/~USERACCOUNT. Each time i access my domain name i see "You have registered your domain now put it work". I have also changed the DNS to that of the webhost but still can not access the site via my domain name except through IP/~USERACCOUNT.

Answer (score 0):

Did you point your domain to your **VPS IP** by adding A-record

Comment: No. Please how do i go about that?

Comment: I just did that now, but after accessing my site via the url i get the response "This site is no longer parked by GoDaddy"

Comment: That message usually appears when the website first goes live. The domain is used to pointing to a parked page, so when you publish your site for the first time, it can sometimes take a while for it to finish the transition